# Removing duplicate elements based on values in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have done more research on removing duplicated elements. 
Most of place , They used the key functions with defined element name. 
In my case , I don't have any defined elements. 
I have tried to modified the examples

Input XML :

```
<Test>
<Req>
  Test
  <A name="Test">Inp1</A>
  <B>Inp2</B>
  <D>Inp3</D>
</Req>
<Resp>
  <A name="Test222">Inp1</A>
  <A>Out1</A>
  <B>Inp1</B>
  <B>Inp2</B>
  <C>Inp3</C>
</Resp>
</Test>
```

XSL  : (I have tried after referring plenty of examples. )

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="unique" match="/Test" use="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('unique',//*)">
        <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique',.)[1])">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output :

```
<Test>
 <Req>
  Test
  <A name="Test">Inp1</A>
  <B>Inp2</B>
  <D>Inp3</D>
</Req>
<Resp>
  <A>Out1</A> 
  <B>Inp1</B> <!-- Inp1 is already available for <A>. Not for <B>. Should not remove this -->
  <C>Inp3</C> <!-- Inp3 is already available for <D>. Not for <C>. Should not remove this -->
</Resp>
</Test>
```

We have match element name and value. (We have to ignore attributes for this).

**NEED SOLUTION ONLY ON XSLT 1.0 or 1.1**

Appreciate help on this. Thanks :)

Comment: Your key should not match `/Test` but the children of `Req` and `Resp`, and it needs to use a concatenation of the element's name and content.

Comment: I have changed to '\Test' to \. Still getting error. Can you please help me with sample XSL.

Comment: I am afraid your additional question is not clear (perhaps you should post a new one?).

Comment: Same solution I want without XSL key.

Comment: Rolled back as per your advise

Comment: I am constructing a variable in XSLT. After constructing , I want to remove duplicate elements with value on that variable.

Comment: I suggest you **do** roll back your question to its original form, and post a new one. These piecemeal comments are unproductive. Post a new question and explain **in detail** what you want and - no less importantly - **why** do you want it (since at this point it seems you are asking how to drive without a car).

Comment: I have rolled the original version.

Comment: Note, there is no such thing as XSLT 1.1. The next version after 1.0 was 2.0, and now there is 3.0. Also, as a kind suggestion, please read: [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="unique" match="Req/* | Resp/*" use="concat(local-name(), '|', .)"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Req/* | Resp/*">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique', concat(local-name(), '|', .))[1])">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your example **input**:

```
<Test>
<Req>
  Test
  <A name="Test">Inp1</A>
  <B>Inp2</B>
  <D>Inp3</D>
</Req>
<Resp>
  <A name="Test222">Inp1</A>
  <A>Out1</A>
  <B>Inp1</B>
  <B>Inp2</B>
  <C>Inp3</C>
</Resp>
</Test>
```

the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
   <Req>
  Test
  <A name="Test">Inp1</A>
      <B>Inp2</B>
      <D>Inp3</D>
   </Req>
   <Resp>
      <A>Out1</A>
      <B>Inp1</B>
      <C>Inp3</C>
   </Resp>
</Test>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike :) This is works only for child elements. If I have duplicated elements , It was not removed. I have editted the request XML now

Comment: I have to remove duplicated elements with value any place under 'Req' and 'Resp'. Thanks :)

Comment: I have found the solution to remove all duplicate elements from Mike's Answer.